# How can I access the Aurelia EventAggregator outside of a class?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to access the Aurelia EventAggregator service at a module level, rather than from inside a class. It's working fine from within a class, where I `@inject` the event aggregator, but not outside.

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class PingerClass {

  constructor(eventAggregator) {
    this.EA = eventAggregator;
  }

  ClassPing() {
    this.EA.publish('ping','Ping from class');
    // ^--- this works fine!
  }
}

function ModulePing() {
  EventAggregator.publish('ping','Ping from module');
  // ^-------- this doesn't work!
}
```

So how do I access the instance of that server in the module? Should I even be trying to do so??

Comment: Is this because you are trying to jump into the aurelia environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EventAggregator` class/constructor-function doesn't have any static methods.  `EventAggregator.publish(...` won't work.  You'll need an instance of the `EventAggregator` and the same instance will need to be used for both publishing and subscribing (multiple event aggregator instances can exist in the same app).

The primary issue is mixing dependency injection (`@inject`) patterns with global patterns is tricky.  One option would be to take DI out of the picture:

```js
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

const bus = new EventAggregator();    

export function publishPing() {
  bus.publish('ping','Ping from module');
}

export function subscribePing(callback) {
  return bus.subscribe('ping', callback);
}
```

I'd say the route you went with the "PingerClass" would be a more idiomatic Aurelia approach.

There's also a mixin that will add the EventAggregator API surface to any object:  https://github.com/aurelia/event-aggregator/blob/master/src/index.js#L133

---

**EDIT**

let's say you want to publish an event using the event aggregator in response to a browser event. Here's how you would do that:

**main.js**

```js
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  ... standard aurelia main.js configure code ...

  let ea = aurelia.container.get(EventAggregator); // get or create the singleton instance managed by the container.
  addEventListener('beforeunload', event => ea.publish('some event', 'some payload'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So my understanding is that the Aurelia DI framework creates a singleton (by default) instance that is injected into the view classes. That's tracked somewhere inside the framework, obviously, so I was hoping there would be a way to get access to that particular instance. The reason for all this is that I have views that subscribe via the more idiomatic Aurelia approach (i.e. @inject)....but would like to publish in response to a browser event that's happening independent of what Aurelia is doing.

Comment: Hrm, as soon as I add the import {EventAggregator}...line to main.js the app falls over: 404 trying to get  ..../dist/aureia-event-aggregator.js. Is there a reason a simple import won't work before Aurelia gets going??

Comment: the event aggregator is an optional plugin, you'll need to install it: `jspm install aurelia-event-aggregator`

Comment: Apologies for ignorance, but if I'm using it successfully in other files within the app is it not already installed? It's just the main.js where the import fails. (everything I'm trying at the moment is extending the latest ES6 skeleton)

Comment: ah! you misspelled the import

Comment: Wasn't a typo - directly copied the import statement from other modules that were working correctly. :) Anyway, after doing the install as you suggested, the import worked....still strikes me as strange: maybe when accessed from another view module the aggregator was loaded as a dependency?  Either way, thanks so much for your prompt replies - really appreciated!